# Is there a way to restart badblocks?

Tags: linux

I have a 1TB drive that I'd like to run badblocks on, but as I understand it would take about 3 days, I'd like to run it in chunks ( say overnight each night ) so the computer it's in is available for use during the day.  Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way to specify from which block `badblocks` should start and the last block, (see `man badblocks`):

> `badblocks [ -svwnfBX ] [ -b block-size ] [ -c blocks_at_once ] [ -e`
>   `max_bad_blocks ] [ -d read_delay_factor ] [ -i input_file ] [ -o`
>   `output_file ] [ -p num_passes ] [ -t test_pattern ] device [`
>   `last-block ] [ first-block ]`

Answer (score 15):

I found this great answer to the question on the [Atlanta Linux Enthusiasts General Mailing List](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.user-groups.ale/92158):

> I finally figured this out after much pondering and reading the man
>   page about 10 times. I thought I'd share it in case someone else needs
>   the info. Googling didn't help much, as those listings usually just
>   quote the man page. When the man page says last-block first-block, it
>   doesn't want you to enter those WORDS, it wants you to enter a NUMBER.
>   It mentions that both are optional, but I cannot figure out how to
>   leave out last-block if I want to specify first block.
>
> Say you stopped your test originally at block 33000001. I would
>   restart the test at one block less, so 33000000.
>
> First, you have to determine what the last block number is on the
>   partition. I've found two ways to do that.
>
> 1. You can start `badblocks` without block numbers. It will tell you
>      the block range it's processing.
>
>    Ex: `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda3`
>
>    And it says something like:
>
>    `Searching for badblocks in read only nondestructive mode from block
>      to 66828373`
>
>    Write down this ending block number. Terminate the test with
>      *CTRL-C* and then enter the command with the block numbers that you want.
> 2. You can use the `fdisk` (or I think also `sfdisk`) command to list
>      partition information. One of the columns of information is # of
>      blocks. Find the number of blocks in the partition you're interested
>      in and SUBTRACT 1 since the blocks are numbered starting at 0.
>
>    `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (That option is a lower case L. In this
>      case, you don't specify the partition number, just the hard drive
>      designation.)
>
>    And it says something like:
>
>    `/dev/sda2 ... /dev/sda3 ... 66828374 /dev/sda4 ...`
>
>    Find the partition you're interested in and read the number of
>      blocks and subtract 1 to find the last block number.
>
>    Now, you can enter the `badblocks` command as follows. Say you want
>      to start testing in the middle of the partition at block 33000000.
>      This example is for non destructive read write mode with `badblocks`
>      list to a text file. If booted from a live cd, you will lose this
>      text file when you reboot.
>
>    `sudo badblocks -nsv -o ~/Desktop/badblocks.txt /dev/sda3 66828373
>      33000000`
>
>    This will test from block 33000000 to the end of the partition. If
>      you specify 66828374 as the last block, as reported in `fdisk`, it
>      will report that block number as bad, but, in fact, that block
>      number doesn't exist.
>
> I hope others may find this useful, as it really confused me for a
>   while.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Ron

Comment: Why subtract 1 to find the last block number?

Answer (score 5):

To make it explicit, say you've interrupted `badblocks`, and have an output that looks like this:

```
root@black:/media/bigdisk# badblocks -sv /dev/sdb1
Checking blocks 0 to 1953512447
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): ^X^C56% done, 39:44 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)

Interrupted at block 284489984
```

You can resume this like so:

```
badblocks -sv /dev/sdb1 1953512447 284489983
```

Note that the block I interrupted the command on is last, and I've decremented it by one (because I'm not sure if being interrupted at that block means it's already been checked).  There is no way to only specify the last block, so far as I can tell; the last block has to be stated, and I've copied that from the initial output.