# How to start badblocks at a specified portion of the drive

Tags: hard-drive, bash, cygwin, dd, bad-blocks

While trying to `dd` the last few blocks of a 200GB Maxtor IDE hard drive, I run into the following error:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress
203901894656 bytes (204 GB, 190 GiB) copied, 7283.07 s, 28.0 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': Permission denied
48621+0 records in
48620+0 records out
208223076351 bytes (208 GB, 194 GiB) copied, 8379.27 s, 24.8 MB/s
```

This error has persisted even after attempting to resume `dd` with `seek=48620`, where 48620 is the amount of blocks to skip. To determine whether this error is the result of bad sectors, I'd like to run `badblocks` in the same way, from where `dd` failed.

This would translate to a `badblocks` command like so:

```
badblocks -svw -b 4000000 -c 500000 -p 1 -o /cygdrive/b/badblocks.txt /dev/sdc 199148543 48620
```

...where `-b 4000000` equates to the 4M block size I used when initially `dd`ing the drive, and 48620 is the `first_block` option that specifies the first block for `badblocks` to start from.

However, this results in one of two errors. Either the non-fatal error...

```
badblocks: Invalid argument during seekrs)
```

...appears throughout the running of the command, or a single fatal error ends it:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The [above error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132193/216754) also persists even when `-c` is set to a more sane value like `2000`.

---

In addition, when I give up on trying to run `badblocks` at the exact block that `dd` failed at and instead try simply increasing the `first_block` option to a sufficiently high number:

```
badblocks -svw -b 4000000 -c 1000000 -p 1 -o /cygdrive/b/users/hashim/desktop/maxtorbadblocks.txt /dev/sdc 199148543 12345678
```

...numerous instances of the following error appear without breaking the command:

```
badblocks: Invalid argument during seekrs)  again get several get the same error.
```

#### How can I start `badblocks` at a specified place in the drive, and thereby save a huge amount of time in the time it takes to run?

Comment: 48620 are 4MB blocks. If you change the size you need to recalculate the amount. However as you wrote 208223076351 bytes, how many bytes are in the harddisk ?

Answer (score 3):

Half an answer, (for now), as to *why* that fails.

The switches in this line are incorrect:

```
badblocks -svw -b 4000000 -c 500000 -p 1 \
          -o /cygdrive/b/badblocks.txt /dev/sdc 199148543 48620
```

The `-b` is for block size, (how many bytes in a block), which is generally a multiple of *512*, usually this would be *1024*, *2048*, or *4096*.  A value of *4,000,000* is not a multiple of *512*, and is larger than any current HDD would use.

The `-c` is how many blocks to test at a time, which multiplied by the value passed to `-b` gives how many bytes would be read at a time -- so `-b 4000000 -c 500000` tells the computer to read *2,000,000,000,000* (two trillion) bytes at a time.

Even worse, the argument `199148543` tells `badblocks` that the file system contains at least that many blocks, and since the blocks are defined by the `-b` switch, `badblocks` reckons the file system contains at least *796,594,172,000,000* bytes, (or *796TB*, almost a Petabyte).

Since the whole disk is *200GB*, `badblocks` halts and prints an error message.

Comment: As I tried to mention in the question: based on my research of `badblocks`, it's my understanding that `-b` refers to logical (filesystem) sectors rather than physical, so not 512 bytes as would likely be the physical default for the device, but the `bs=4M` that I specified when initially zeroing the drive with `dd` (which I assumed was in megabytes rather than mebibytes, hence the *4,000,000* rather than *4,194,304*). I figured that because I'd already used `dd` to write to the drive with that block size...

Comment: ...I would need to keep the block size the same in `badblocks -b` in order to have the number of blocks be the same and therefore get to the block on the HDD that I was looking for. Is any of the above incorrect?

Comment: Your explanation of what causes the error message does make sense, but that number is shown by both `badblocks` and `cat /proc/partitions` as the number of total blocks for the device - I obtained it using the [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/693000/323079).

Comment: @Hashim, Re "_...but **that** number..._": sorry, but it's unclear which number is meant -- please specify exactly which number.

Comment: The total size of the drive in blocks: 199148543.

Comment: @Hashim "I assumed was in megabytes rather than mebibytes" – Wrong. `man dd` says the `M` suffix means `1024*1024`. – "The total size of the drive in blocks: 199148543" – In blocks of what size? `/proc/partitions` uses 1KiB. In your previous question you mentioned a disk of 200 GB, this would almost fit. Almost, because this odd number looks odd. I would expect 199148544 blocks of 1KiB (numbered 0-199148543). If you tell `badblocks` to use blocks of 4MiB, you need to recompute: you have (about?) 48620.25 of them. Could it be `dd` under `cygwin` got lost because of this last fractional "block"?

Comment: @Hashim Check if `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 seek=398295040` yields an error in the first place. This is `… bs=4M seek=48620` recomputed, but the last block of data will be written in full for sure (no fractional part) because common sector sizes are 512B and 4KiB, so one way or another every disk must contain some integer number of 512B "chunks".